# Есть ли у midjourney API для Python?

Tags: python, api, искусственный-интеллект

Знаю, что у Chat-GPT есть человеческий API для Python, качаешь их либу, вызываешь метод, генерируешь ответ. Есть ли такая же у midjourney и где купить/получить токен ?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется нет, но есть API от Open AI для рисования картинок.
Вот ссылка - https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/images/introduction, тут написан код который нужно использовать.
Тут так же как и при генерации текста нужно получить API key, вот ссылка на страничку где можно его получить - https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

UPD: Есть некоторое количество сервисов предоставляющих АПИ доступ к midjourney. Например: [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

В последнее время появилось множество апи прослоек, ты можешь поискать по ключевому слову TNL (хорошее комьюнити в телеграмме, правда в послежнее время совсем нестабильно работает - надеюсь поправят). Или множество других сервисов, тот же [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai) или ему подобные

Answer (score 0):

Можете в Fabula AI спросить, у них есть АПИ для доступа к ИИ продуктам. Там не только text2image, большой ассортимент.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.